# Landlord Slow on Critical Repairs

Tags: united-states, landlord, new-jersey

I moved into an apartment in northern New Jersey about a month ago. The apartment building contains 3 total units, one on each floor. I live in the 2nd story unit which was renovated right before I moved in. The “property manager” (landlord for all intents and purposes) lives on the 3rd floor, but his unit is being renovated so he does not currently live there.

It has been raining a couple days a week here recently and we noticed water is leaking into our apartment. We first notified the landlord about a leak two weeks ago.

Several more leaks have since occured, with the worst wave coming today after a heavy thunderstorm. We have notified the landlord each time we noticed a new leak, and he keeps saying either him or his contractor will take a look, but we havent received any summary of the action steps he’s taken on this.

After the heavy thunderstorm today, when my roommate got home from work he noticed someone was in our apartment and had attempted to clean up the water that ended up on the bathroom and living room floors, as wells as numerous additional leaks.

Ideally, what we want to happen is as follows: He starts communicating that he has received our complaints and tells us what he is doing to remedy them (and then actually fixes the issues) in a timely manner.

If the slow response continues, we want some kind of compensation (one month off rent?) for his lack of communication and attention to the issue. Ideally, we would like to stay in the apartment as it is very nice and in a great location. Ultimately, we think the 3rd floor renovations opened up the door for all these leaks and this shouldnt be an issue going forward, but regardless its been extremely inconvenient.

**How can we get the landlord to accomplish either of the above?**

If this is the wrong site for this question, please let me know and I’ll move it.